# What is the goal of the tags in service settings in symfony2

Tags: symfony, event-listener, service-object

In this service for an eventListener, it used the **tags** item:

```
services:
    app.exception_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

1. What is the goal of tags item?
2. How define the **name** (name:kernel.event_listener) into this tags item?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags provide a name-key-value attribute that can be attached to a service. By themselves, they don't do anything, but other services can take advantage of tags to do something more interesting.

In the particular example you've given, when the container is built, a compiler pass for the event listener looks for services with the name `kernel.event_listener`, and registers that services as an event listener for the `kernel.exception` event.

Tag names themselves aren't defined anywhere; but if you create a `CompilerPass` that's registered with the container, you can search for services that are tagged with a particular name and do something useful with them. (Such as registering event handlers, as described above.)

You can find more information about tagged services from the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html), including an example of a simple `CompilerPass`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The value in the tag names is used in the process()  method in CompilerPass to find all services are tagged with it by using findTaggedServiceIds(value) method.